# How to remove Python version shown in zsh terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, python-2.7

How can I remove this "via python v2.7.17" from my terminal?
[image]

Sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu and I can't find any way to remove this from my terminal.

Comment: Please provide OS & release; recent releases of Ubuntu no longer come with python 2.7 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to edit your configuration file at `~/.zshrc`.

I'm using Zsh as shell, themed with powerlevel10k. In my config file there is something like this:

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_VIRTUALENV_SHOW_PYTHON_VERSION=false
```

Hope it'd be helpful!